# html align doesn't work when loop

Tags: html, css, foreach, jstl

```
<c:forEach items="${freeList}" var="freeList">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddenFreeboardCd" value="${freeList.freeboardCd}">
        <c:if test="${sessionScope.generalId!=null}">
          <span class="bookmarkSpan"></span> 
        </c:if>
      </td>
  </table>
</c:forEach>
```

align property is doesn't work from secondary loop

any idea?

Comment: you have a missing </tr> at the end.

Comment: first thing why you are creating table on each loop? second on which layout you want output?

Comment: @Sreekanth 
I made a mistake when I copied. 
It's exists in the actual code.

Comment: @SanjayPatel I'm making a guest book.
The number of tables in the database will be repeated